# Regular expression optimization

Tags: python, regex, optimization, pcre

I need to optimize this regular expression.

```
^(.+?)\|[\w\d]+?\s+?(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d\s+?\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d)[\s\d]+?\s+?(\d+?)\s+?\d+?\s+?(\d+?)$
```

The input is something like this:

```
-tpf0q16|856B             11/20/2014      00:00:00.015    0          0          0          0          0          689        14         689        703        702          701        700
```

I'm already replaced all gready matches with lazy matches but this didn't helps. I've use DOTALL but it didn't help either. I use python and PCRE (re module), I know about re2 but I can't use it :(

Comment: Why are you using a regex for that (rather than e.g. `split` and parse each element)?

Comment: What's your expected output? is this `^(.+?)\|[\w\d]+?\s+?(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s+?\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})(?:\s+\d+){12}$` you want?

Comment: what do you want to fetch, would you tell me?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/zU7dA5/7 ?????

Comment: If your problem also is that the regex takes long to find all results on a lot of text you should try to see if there is precompile option in python for regex as it is in C#. Esesntialy the regex takes longed to "boot" up but otherwise does the work more then twice as fast. This is very good if you have a lot of text to go through

Comment: @jonrsharpe because regex is 40% faster then split in my case.

Comment: @AvinashRaj this regex matches ("-tpf0q16", "11/20/2014      00:00:00.015", "702", "700").

Comment: @vks what the idea? You remove two last capture groups.

Comment: @Vajura it is possible to compile regular expressions in python too.

Comment: yep, your regex would capture the above values. What's wrong with that? Could you provide the expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj nothing wrong. I don't want to alter behaviour of the regex, I want to optimize it!

Comment: @Lazin you should definetly try that + optimized version of your regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to get rid of the unneeded reluctant (a.k.a. "lazy") quantifiers.  According to RegexBuddy, your regex:

```
^(.+?)\|[\w\d]+?\s+?(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d\s+?\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d)[\s\d]+?\s+?(\d+?)\s+?\d+?\s+?(\d+?)$
```

...takes 6425 steps to match your sample string.  This one:

```
^(.+?)\|[\w\d]+\s+(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d)[\s\d]+\s+(\d+)\s+\d+\s+(\d+)$
```

...takes 716 steps.

Reluctant quantifiers reduce backtracking by doing more work up front.  Your regex wasn't prone to excessive backtracking, so the reluctant quantifiers were *adding* quite a lot to the workload.

This version brings it down to 237 steps:

```
^([^|]+)\|\w+\s+(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d)(?:\s+\d+)+\s+(\d+)\s+\d+\s+(\d+)$
```

It also removes some noise, like the backslash before `/`; and `[\w\d]`, which is exactly the same as `\w`.

Comment: What tool do you use to count regex steps?

Comment: [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/index.html).  The "steps" don't map directly to what really happens in a particular regex engine (they're all a little different, in various ways), but they're a very useful overall metric.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more optimized.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "-tpf0q16|856B             11/20/2014      00:00:00.015    0          0          0          0          0          689        14         689        703        702          701        700"
>>> re.findall(r'(?m)^([^|]+)\|[\w\d]+?\s+?(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})[\s\d]+?(\d+)\s+\d+\s+(\d+?)$', s)
[('-tpf0q16', '11/20/2014      00:00:00.015', '702', '700')]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zU7dA5/11)